# Version of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

I would like to proof the following theorem.

> Let $(X,Y)$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Supposte that $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ has density $f(.,.)$ with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $E[|X|]<\infty$ holds, then $$E[X|Y]=\frac{\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x,Y)dx}{\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,Y)dx}$$

I started like this: Let $A=Y^{-1}(B)$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$
\int_A\frac{\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x,Y)dx}{\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,Y)dx}dP
\\=\int_B\frac{\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x,y)dx}{\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)dx} P\circ Y^{-1}(dy)
\\=\int_B(\frac{\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x,y)dx}{\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)dx}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)dx)\ dy
\\=\int_B\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x,y)dx\ dy
$$
But i am not able to show that the last term is equal to $E[X1_{Y^{-1}(B)}]$.

Comment: Everything is fine (except some minor tecnicalities). The last step is to use the formula $E[g(X,Y)] = \iint_{\mathbb R^2} g(x,y) f(x,y) dx\, dy$ for $g(x,y) = x1_{y\in B}$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your last identity, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_B\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x, y) dx dy &= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}x 1_{B}(y) f(x, y) dx dy = E\left(X1_B(Y) \right).
\end{align*}
$$$$
Alternatively, note that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) dx
\end{align*}
is the marginal density function for $Y$.  Then, for any bounded Borel-measurable function $g$, 
\begin{align*}
E\left( X g(Y) \right) &=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}xg(y)f(x, y) dx dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(y)dy \int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x, y) dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x, y) dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) dx}g(y) \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) dx\,  dy\\
&=E\left(\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x, Y) dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, Y) dx} g(Y)\right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E(X \mid Y) &=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x, Y) dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, Y) dx} .
\end{align*}