# Deduce the formula for conditional expectation via basic definition in sigma-algebra.

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

I am trying to deduce the formula for conditional expectation
$$\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx,$$
through the basic definition of conditional expectation.

Recall the definition of conditonal expectation $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{H})$, suppose probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{F}$, $\forall H \in \mathcal{H}$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{H} \mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{H})d\mathbb{P} = \int_{H} Xd\mathbb{P}. 
\end{equation}
My try:

Basically, we consider the $\mathcal{H} = \sigma(Y)$ is the $\sigma-$algebra generated by $Y$, the definition is equivalent to, $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}$,
$$\int_{Y^{-1}(B)} \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)d\mathbb{P} = \int_{Y^{-1}(B)} Xd\mathbb{P}.$$ 
Then, Taking the $B = (\infty, y),$

$$Left = \int_{\infty}^y \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y = y)d\mathbb{P}_Y = \int_{\infty}^y \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y = y)dF_Y(y) = \int_{\infty}^y \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y = y)\cdot f_Y(y)dy.$$
This result is pretty close to the solution. However, I have no idea to prove the $Right$, can anyone show me the proof for the following equation? Thanks.
$$Right = \int_{Y^{-1}(B)}Xd\mathbb{P} = \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, by definition (see [Shiryaev](https://www.amazon.ca/Probability-Albert-N-Shiryaev/dp/0387945490/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476803264&sr=8-1&keywords=shiryaev+probability)), $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y)$ is a Borel measurable function such that, for any Borel set $B$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{Y \in B} X dP = \int_B \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y) P_Y(dy),
\end{align*}
where $P_Y(dy)$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by the distribution function of $Y$, that is $P_Y(B) = P(Y \in B)$. Since
\begin{align*}
\int_{Y \in B} X dP &= \mathbb{E}(X 1_{\{Y\in B\}})\\
&=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}x1_{\{y\in B\}}f_{X,Y}(x, y) dxdy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} dx\right)1_{\{y\in B\}}f_Y(y) dy\\
&=\int_B\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} dx\right)f_Y(y) dy\\
&=\int_B\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} dx\right) P_Y(dy),
\end{align*}
we deduce that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} dx.
\end{align*}
See also related answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949075/version-of-conditional-expectation/1953804#1953804), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922714/definition-of-conditional-expectation-of-y-given-x/1928218#1928218), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866063/define-the-function-g-y-efx-y-show-that-g-is-borel-measurable-and/1866805#1866805).

Comment: Great solution, thank you very much!